# Python 3.x/json package cannot convert this json string to list

Tags: python, json, list

I have this string which I wanted to convert to a list:

```
"{'Attributes': {'a', 'b', 'h'}, 'Group3': {'c'}, 'Group2': {'s', 'm', 'r', 'ac'}}"
```

I tried `json.loads()` and it is giving me this error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

It is coming from another program and I cannot control the quoting... single or double quote

Environment: Python 3.x with import json

My code:

```
mystr =  "{'Attributes': {'a', 'b', 'h'}, 'Group3': {'c'}, 'Group2': {'s', 'm', 'r', 'ac'}}"
mylist = json.loads(mystr)
```

I expected it to be a valid list

Comment: `json.loads(mystr.replace("'", "\""))`

Comment: Perhaps just a terminology mistake, but nothing in that json is a _list_.  `{'a', 'b', 'h'}` is a _set_.

Comment: Your string does not contain valid JSON, so a json parser is going to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Your string is not a valid JSON.

The following should do the trick:

```
import json

mystr =  "{'Attributes': ['a', 'b', 'h'], 'Group3': ['c'], 'Group2': ['s', 'm', 'r', 'ac']}" 
mydict = json.loads(mystr.replace("'", "\"")) 
print(mydict)

>>> {'Attributes': ['a', 'b', 'h'], 'Group3': ['c'], 'Group2': ['s', 'm', 'r', 'ac']}
```

Comment: Got it - I think the other program is spitting out this invalid json. Let me work with that part and if possible change it. Thanks a lot.